# AddListener(DevToolsEventListener \*) subscribing a listener to the already connected DevToolsClient error with ChromeDriver and Selenium Java

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium4

I am using:

1. chrome driver version 110.0.5481.178
2. My System Chrome Version 110.0.5481.178
3. Java version 17.0.5
4. Java server 4.8.1 also previously used 4.7**

The system is showing the below-mentioned error:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 110.0.5481.77 (65ed616c6e8ee3fe0ad64fe83796c020644d42af-refs/branch-heads/5481@{#839}) on port 18129
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
\[1677347917.891\]\[WARNING\]: virtual void DevToolsClientImpl::AddListener(DevToolsEventListener \*) subscribing a listener to the already connected DevToolsClient. Connection notification will not arrive.
```

I have executed the code with different versions of the chrome driver and my system's chrome version but nothing works for me and i am using java with selenium by using chrome.

Kindly help me out in fixing the issue and let me know what exactly is the issue and provide me complete step-by-step instructions regarding how can I fix this issue.

[image]

I have tried to fix this out with different combination of chrome driver and my chrome version and also changed the java server from 4.7 to 4.8.1 but nothing works for me.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1677347917.891\]\[WARNING\]: virtual void DevToolsClientImpl::AddListener(DevToolsEventListener \*) subscribing a listener to the already connected DevToolsClient. Connection notification will not arrive.
```

...implies that [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was successfull initiated.

The *WARNING* you observe is a *Listener* related error and it won't effect your tests. hence you can ignore for the time being.